# Disabling interference from my clicks from outside of a selenium test

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I wrote a script in Python using Selenium to automate a waiting task on a ticket booking website. I am waiting for a ticket to be available and then autofill a form to reach the payment page.

Pseudocode:

1. Login at the ticketing website.
2. Click on "Book Ticket" button.
3. Select the category of the ticket required.
4. Check whether its available.
5. If its not available then go to step 3 for it to trigger and find availability status again.
6. If its available, then proceed to the next page.
7. Fill a form and proceed to the next page
8. Click on "Pay" button on this page to reach a payment page. Send me an email that triggers an alarm on my phone so that I can finish stuff manually before the payment session expires.

My problem is that while this test is running if I start clicking anywhere outside the browser window where the webdriver is running this test, it detects it as part of that test leading to unexpected results and stoppages.

I have explored options like headless browsing but I need to get to the payment page and then finish payment manually. I don't believe one can go from headless to head within the same webdriver session.

Please suggest solutions and other potentially pitfalls that I might encounter while testing this script.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Code: (excuse the exorbitant use of sleep. I know there are other better looking wait features in the library itself)

```
#Selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
# from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

#For emailing me
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

#sleep to avoid loading spinner overlays
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
action = ActionChains(driver)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

LOGIN_PAGE = #LOGIN PAGE of the ticketing website

def main():

    driver.get(LOGIN_PAGE)
    time.sleep(2)

    #closes the cookies dialog
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/button").click()

    #get the input tags: username, password
    tags = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//input')
    #ENTER YOUR ACCOUNT DETAILS
    tags[0].send_keys(#Username)
    tags[1].send_keys(#Password)

    #Login button
    submitButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/app-login/section/div/div/mat-card/form/button")
    submitButton.click()

    time.sleep(4)

    #Book ticket button
    bookButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/div/app-dashboard/section/div/div[2]/button")
    bookButton.click()

    time.sleep(3)

    #Pressing drowpdown for options
    dds = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//mat-select")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", dds[0])
    category_1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//mat-option")
    action.move_to_element(category_1[10]).perform()
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", category_1[10])

    time.sleep(3)

    result = None

    while result is None or "No tickets available" in result.text:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", dds[1])
        categories = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//mat-option")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", categories[5])

        time.sleep(3)

        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", dds[1])
        categories = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//mat-option")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", categories[4])

        time.sleep(3)

        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", dds[2])
        subcats = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//mat-option")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", subcats[0])
        # print(subcats[0].text)

        time.sleep(2)

        result = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/div/app-booking/section/form/mat-card[1]/form/div[4]/div")


    #Email

    mail_content = "Ticket now available. For: " + result.text
    sender_address = #Gmail address with third party apps activated
    sender_pass = '#password
    receiver_address = #notification email address
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['From'] = sender_address
    message['To'] = receiver_address
    message['Subject'] = 'Ticket available'
    message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))
    session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    session.starttls()
    session.login(sender_address, sender_pass)
    text = message.as_string()
    session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
    session.quit()

    #Proceed button
    contd = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/div/app-booking/section/form/mat-card[2]/button")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", contd)

    time.sleep(4)

    #Fill form
    rollers = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//mat-select")

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", rollers[0])
    gen = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//mat-option")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", gen[1])

    #Form filling
    form_inputs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//input')
    form_inputs[0].send_keys()
    form_inputs[1].send_keys()
    form_inputs[2].send_keys()
    form_inputs[3].send_keys()
    form_inputs[4].send_keys()

    time.sleep(4)

    save_butt = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/div/app-checkout/section/mat-card[2]/app-dynamic-form/div/div/app-dynamic-control/div/div/div[2]/button")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", save_butt)
    
    time.sleep(7)

    contd_2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/div/app-checkout-details/section/mat-card[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", contd_2)

    time.sleep(3)

    #selecting the most recent date
    dates = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("date-available")
    dates[0].click()
    slots = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input")
    slots[2].click()

    time.sleep(2)

    contd_3 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/div/app-review/section/mat-card[2]/div/div[2]/button")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", contd_3)

    time.sleep(3)

    contd_4 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/div/app-final/section/mat-card[2]/div/div[2]/button")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", contd_4)

    time.sleep(3)

    check_1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/app-root/div/app-payment/section/form/mat-card[1]/div[8]/div/mat-checkbox/label/span[1]")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", check_1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I believe you had tried something, right? Please add that code in your question by [edit]ing.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "this test is running if I start clicking anywhere outside the browser window where the webdriver is running this test" does outside mean different tab of the browser or on the desktop ? if you are browsing in the web window while running the test , can you try a different browser app . i.e if u are using chrome for selenium test . try the clicks in Mozilla or Internet explorer and check if issue still exists ?

Comment: @Xitiz Yep. I'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: @NukalaRaghavaAditya I have tried:
1. Minimizing
2. Different browser like you mentioned.
But the problem is that its picking up my clicks from literally anywhere on the screen. It doesn't have to be on the same chrome window, tab, etc. Because my loop for waiting depends on clicks and drop-downs, any extra scroll or unwanted click jeopardizes the flow of the script.

Comment: I am sure you have thought about this , but can u double check if your loop of waiting depends on a particular element click instead of Generic click ? WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(<element_attributes>);
element.click();

Comment: @Xitiz Code Added

Comment: @NukalaRaghavaAditya My loop condition is a string comparison.